# Saving values in forms

Tags: php, forms

Currently i have a form that is used for booking a certain venue etc. All fields in the form requires a value. If any of them are filled out wrong, it comes up with a message above the form stating which fields are incorrect. With this, when it returns the error, it comes up with the previously entered values in the fields already entered.

However once successful, the next screen is used to confirm the booking using a yes and no button for each. When clicking yes, it saves all the field values to the database.

But when i click no, it returns back to the form. Up till here everything is correct. The one issue i'm having is when a user clicks No and is returned to the form, the values aren't already entered in the form. The form is completely empty. How would i go about getting this done?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a few different ways. For example, could use `$_SESSION` variables.

After form submit:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_POST['value_from_form'] = $_SESSION['first_form_value'];
    /*REST OF YOUR CODE*/
```

User click no

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!empty($_SESSION)) {
        echo "<input type='name' value='" . $_SESSION['first_form_value'] . "'>";
        /*REST OF CODE*/
    }
    else {
        echo "No session variables";
    }
```

Comment: exists isn't a function.\

Comment: @RPM Sorry, your right, I meant `!empty`. Thanks for that good catch!